# Google Cloud Container: Create a docker container from a Dockerfile

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

Is it possible to create a docker container in a Google Container Engine cluster, using a `dockerfile`, which builds an image on-the-fly and deploy in cluster,
rather than creating an image first and uploading it to a Google Container Registry, and then using it from there?

I feel like that is cumbersome, and there should be a way to create containers in cluster directly using a dockerfile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to do this in Google Container Engine. Google Container Engine is designed to help orchestrate container deployment and does not itself provide a source -> deployment workflow.

You may want to look at [Google App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs) or [Openshift 3](https://www.openshift.com/enterprise/) (which is built on Kubernetes) as a more fully featured platform-as-a-service offering.

You can also build this type of tooling on top of a Google Container Engine cluster yourself as all of the building blocks are available.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, but PaaS is not portable and we will have to stick to the particular service provider, and porting to another platform will cost some effort to migrate. So don't want to go for PaaS

Comment: Sure, that's part of the benefit of using Kubernetes. I think that Openshift 3 may be more portable than you think (since it runs on top of Kubernetes) but I understand if you are hesitant to commit. As I mentioned, the alternative is to build your own source -> deployment workflow on top of Kubernetes, which would allow you to run it anywhere that you can deploy Kubernetes.

Comment: Right Now Google is our cloud provider, but need to keep it portable to anywhere else in future. So it will explore more as per your suggestion on  "build your own source -> deployment workflow on top of Kubernetes".. Tnx

Answer (score 1):

One service to take a look at when constructing a workflow is [Google Container Builder](https://cloud.google.com/container-builder/docs/getting-started), which can simplify the process of building a container from source and pushing it to Google Container Registry.

It is currently a fairly low level service, but offers some advantages for environments where it may be impractical to run `docker build` locally.